# Adding class to gravatar img in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, gravatar

I've been trying to use get_avatar to display the author's gravatar under each post **in wordpress template** with applied class but I couldn`t find a way to add class="pic-2" to gravatar image code or even changing gravatar heigth and width to 100px and 77px respectively

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID'), 32 ); ?>
```

Any help guys ??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this would be to use a filter, rather than using jQuery as George suggests. You would simply add this to your theme's *functions.php* file.

```
add_filter('get_avatar','add_gravatar_class');

function add_gravatar_class($class) {
    $class = str_replace("class='avatar", "class='avatar pic-2", $class);
    return $class;
}
```

*Note, I've not tested this, but believe it will work. See [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/customize-get_avatar-css-class) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the WordPress Codex for more info:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Gravatars

For the size, try wrapping the second parameter like so:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID'), $size = '96' ); ?>
```

The default html output is like so:

```
<img alt='' src='http://gravatarurl_or_default' class='avatar avatar-$size' height='$size' width='$size' />
```

You can style the default class 'avatar' in place of 'pic-2'. If you still want to add a class , you can do it via javascript like so:

```
$("img[class='avatar']").addClass("pic-2");
```

Hope this helps! : )

Comment: Thanks for that link! I got mine to work :D http://thelifeleveler.com/the-most-important-first-step-to-self-improvement/

Answer (score 1):

If @Ryan answer (marked as solution) does'nt work for you, try to change

```
add_filter('get_avatar','add_gravatar_class');

function add_gravatar_class($class) {
    $class = str_replace("class='avatar", "class='avatar pic-2", $class);
    return $class;
}
```

into

```
add_filter('get_avatar','add_gravatar_class');

function add_gravatar_class($class) {
    $class = str_replace('class="avatar', 'class="avatar pic-2', $class);
    return $class;
}
```

This start's work for me after replace " with '.

Sorry that I didn't write this as a comment to that answer, but I don't have 50 reputation to comment other posts.

Comment: Thank you, finally found a solution to this:)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this for future searchers, very simple string manipulation which is probably a bit safer if they change the function in the future e.g. it'll likely always have a 'class'.

```
    $grvimg = get_avatar('email address', 200);
    $grvimg = explode("class='", $grvimg);
    $grvimg[1] = 'your-class ' . $grvimg[1];
    $grvimg = $grvimg[0] . $grvimg[1];
    echo $grvimg;
```