# WordPress - get_avatar add custom class

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I'm using the get_avatar function to display user's avatar.

Every parameter in the function works except `I cannot get any output from the $args parameter.`

I'm simply trying to add a class to the user's avatar image. I've consulted the [get_avatar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) codex and other answers here but do not see what I'm doing wrong.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$user_avatar = get_avatar($user_id, 35, '', '', array('class' => 'border-circle'));    
echo $user_avatar;
```

Comment: You can pass argument like this also:  $args = array( 'class' => array( 'd-block', 'mx-auto' ) );                
$user_avatar = get_avatar( $user_id, $size, $default, $alt,$args);

Comment: @PPL I had tried your suggestion and a few others but still don't see any class being added to the image. I do not think it works as it says.

Comment: Please provide your code, which you have  tried?

Comment: I had tried adding this filter ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542796/adding-class-to-gravatar-img-in-wordpress ), different attempts to call the same array into the $args parameter and defined all new defaults for every argument...I've since deleted these snippets. But I want to know why it won't work as it's written in the documentation. If the other parameters work the $args should work too. Otherwise, I think I will just add a CSS class to my theme. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a WordPress theme with Bootstrap.

This worked for me.

```
<?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 50, '', '', $args = array( 'scheme' => 'https', 'class' => 'mr-3' ) ); ?>
```